# Nuxt 3 checkbox is not checked with v-model data

Tags: vuejs3, pinia, vue-reactivity

I have a checkbox that fill v-model with data from store, the code look like this

```
 <input 
   type="checkbox" 
   class="form-check-input" 
   id="checkActive"
   :checked="labelStore.active"
   v-model="labelStore.active"
>
   {{labelStore.active}}
```

When i load from store is not setting de checkbox active. If i put only checked v-bind is working but i can't update store with the right way

my store code

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';


export const useLabelStore = defineStore({
    id: 'label',
    state: () => ({
        id: '',
        name: '',
        active: false,

        isLoading: false,

        idToDelete: '',


    }),
});
```

Comment: Please also share your store code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved setting this options to checkbox, the problem occured because the value that is seted in store from endpoint are 1 or 0 not true or false

```
:true-value="1"
:false-value="0"
```